# Scroll Top and Add Effect While Loading

Tags: jquery, css, loading

I have posts like that :

```
<div class="my-posts loadme">
 ....All Posts here...
</div>
```

When I press next posts button, i will get new posts. Now, I want add effect while loading and after loading like:

When next-button is clicked, page will scroll up at the top of `.my-posts` and the old data will be added fadeout effect, new data will be added fadein effect and also add with *gif images to `loadme` class.

Here is click event :

```
$("#next").click(function () {
     //isLoading
     if (i.loadAjax) {
         $(".loadme").css("background", "white url(img.gif) no-repeat");
     }
 }
//After Loading
```

New Data appended like:

```
$("div.my-posts").html(newdata);
```

It means I want effect like demo : http://themes.themolitor.com/wpnovelist/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#next").click(function()
{

var opts = {
  lines: 9, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 29, // The length of each line
  width: 14, // The line thickness
  radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 28, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
  speed: 1.2, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
  left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};
var target = document.getElementById('spinner');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);


var refresh = false;
data = {
    'action': 'manage_reports'
    }; 
var url = 'includes/ajax_reports.php';
$.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    cache: false, 
    url: url, 
    data: data, 
    error:function(result)
    {

        $("#display").html(result);
    },
    success:function(result)
    {
                    $("display").hide();

        $("#display").html(result).slideDown('slow');
        if(refresh) location.reload(); 
    }

});
```

}); 
I'm using a spin.min file that consists of:

```
 (function(t,e)
{if(typeof exports=="object")module.exports=e();else if(typeof define=="function"&&

define.amd)define(e);else t.Spinner=e()})(this,function(){"use strict";var t=["webkit","Moz","ms","O"],e={},i;function o(t,e){var i=document.createElement(t||"div"),o;for(o in e)i[o]=e[o];return i}function n(t){for(var e=1,i=arguments.length;e<i;e++)t.appendChild(arguments[e]);return t}var r=function(){var t=o("style",{type:"text/css"});n(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],t);return t.sheet||t.styleSheet}();function s(t,o,n,s){var a=["opacity",o,~~(t*100),n,s].join("-"),f=.01+n/s*100,l=Math.max(1-(1-t)/o*(100-f),t),d=i.substring(0,i.indexOf("Animation")).toLowerCase(),u=d&&"-"+d+"-"||"";if(!e[a]){r.insertRule("@"+u+"keyframes "+a+"{"+"0%{opacity:"+l+"}"+f+"%{opacity:"+t+"}"+(f+.01)+"%{opacity:1}"+(f+o)%100+"%{opacity:"+t+"}"+"100%{opacity:"+l+"}"+"}",r.cssRules.length);e[a]=1}return a}function a(e,i){var o=e.style,n,r;if(o[i]!==undefined)return i;i=i.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+i.slice(1);for(r=0;r<t.length;r++){n=t[r]+i;if(o[n]!==undefined)return n}}function f(t,e){for(var i in e)t.style[a(t,i)||i]=e[i];return t}function l(t){for(var e=1;e<arguments.length;e++){var i=arguments[e];for(var o in i)if(t[o]===undefined)t[o]=i[o]}return t}function d(t){var e={x:t.offsetLeft,y:t.offsetTop};while(t=t.offsetParent)e.x+=t.offsetLeft,e.y+=t.offsetTop;return e}var u={lines:12,length:7,width:5,radius:10,rotate:0,corners:1,color:"#000",direction:1,speed:1,trail:100,opacity:1/4,fps:20,zIndex:2e9,className:"spinner",top:"auto",left:"auto",position:"relative"};function p(t){if(typeof this=="undefined")return new p(t);this.opts=l(t||{},p.defaults,u)}p.defaults={};l(p.prototype,{spin:function(t){this.stop();var e=this,n=e.opts,r=e.el=f(o(0,{className:n.className}),{position:n.position,width:0,zIndex:n.zIndex}),s=n.radius+n.length+n.width,a,l;if(t){t.insertBefore(r,t.firstChild||null);l=d(t);a=d(r);f(r,{left:(n.left=="auto"?l.x-a.x+(t.offsetWidth>>1):parseInt(n.left,10)+s)+"px",top:(n.top=="auto"?l.y-a.y+(t.offsetHeight>>1):parseInt(n.top,10)+s)+"px"})}r.setAttribute("role","progressbar");e.lines(r,e.opts);if(!i){var u=0,p=(n.lines-1)*(1-n.direction)/2,c,h=n.fps,m=h/n.speed,y=(1-n.opacity)/(m*n.trail/100),g=m/n.lines;(function v(){u++;for(var t=0;t<n.lines;t++){c=Math.max(1-(u+(n.lines-t)*g)%m*y,n.opacity);e.opacity(r,t*n.direction+p,c,n)}e.timeout=e.el&&setTimeout(v,~~(1e3/h))})()}return e},stop:function(){var t=this.el;if(t){clearTimeout(this.timeout);if(t.parentNode)t.parentNode.removeChild(t);this.el=undefined}return this},lines:function(t,e){var r=0,a=(e.lines-1)*(1-e.direction)/2,l;function d(t,i){return f(o(),

{position:"absolute",width:e.length+e.width+"px",height:e.width+"px",background:t,boxShadow:i,transformOrigin:"left",transform:"rotate("+~~(360/e.lines*r+e.rotate)+"deg) translate("+e.radius+"px"+",0)",borderRadius:(e.corners*e.width>>1)+"px"})}for(;r<e.lines;r++){l=f(o(),{position:"absolute",top:1+~(e.width/2)+"px",transform:e.hwaccel?"translate3d(0,0,0)":"",opacity:e.opacity,animation:i&&s(e.opacity,e.trail,a+r*e.direction,e.lines)+" "+1/e.speed+"s linear infinite"});if(e.shadow)n(l,f(d("#000","0 0 4px "+"#000"),{top:2+"px"}));n(t,n(l,d(e.color,"0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)")))}return t},opacity:function(t,e,i){if(e<t.childNodes.length)t.childNodes[e].style.opacity=i}});function c(){function t(t,e){return o("<"+t+' xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:vml" class="spin-vml">',e)}r.addRule(".spin-vml","behavior:url(#default#VML)");p.prototype.lines=function(e,i){var o=i.length+i.width,r=2*o;function s(){return f(t("group",{coordsize:r+" "+r,coordorigin:-o+" "+-o}),{width:r,height:r})}var a=-(i.width+i.length)*2+"px",l=f(s(),{position:"absolute",top:a,left:a}),d;function u(e,r,a){n(l,n(f(s(),{rotation:360/i.lines*e+"deg",left:~~r}),n(f(t("roundrect",{arcsize:i.corners}),{width:o,height:i.width,left:i.radius,top:-i.width>>1,filter:a}),t("fill",{color:i.color,opacity:i.opacity}),t("stroke",{opacity:0}))))}if(i.shadow)for(d=1;d<=i.lines;d++)u(d,-2,"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2,makeshadow=1,shadowopacity=.3)");for(d=1;d<=i.lines;d++)u(d);return n(e,l)};p.prototype.opacity=function(t,e,i,o){var n=t.firstChild;o=o.shadow&&o.lines||0;if(n&&e+o<n.childNodes.length){n=n.childNodes[e+o];n=n&&n.firstChild;n=n&&n.firstChild;if(n)n.opacity=i}}}var h=f(o("group"),{behavior:"url(#default#VML)"});if(!a(h,"transform")&&h.adj)c();else i=a(h,"animation");return p});
```